# Создание View после коммита фрагментов

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment

Кнопка "btn" создается в начале linearLayout, а виджеты новостей идут уже после нее. Как реализовать обратный порядок?

```
public void loadPosts() {
        //создание виджетов новостей
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        for(int a = 0; a < 5; i++, a++){
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.news_layout, new PostFragment(i));
        }
        fragmentTransaction.commit();// завершение создания новостей
        // создание кнопки
        Button btn = new Button(getContext());
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                loadPosts();
                LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) view.getParent();
                ll.removeView(view);
            }
        });
        btn.setText("Еще...");
        btn.setTextSize(18);
        btn.setWidth(100);
        btn.setHeight(30);
        LinearLayout ll = root.findViewById(R.id.news_layout);
        ll.addView(btn); // завершение создания кнопки
    }
```

Comment: addView (View child, int index);

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно вас понял вы хотите, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку она исчезала и на ее месте появлялись новости в порядке, обратном тому, в котором их добавили во вью. Если так, то вам нужно просто писать 
`layout.addView(item, 0);`
Новый объект будет добавляться на первое место в списке

Comment: В том то и проблема, что кнопка находится в верху экрана, а должна быть в конце списка.

Comment: если в лайауте есть кнопка, и вы вставите новость с помощью addView(view, 0), то она появится над кнопкой